# MySQL function does not return correct result

Tags: mysql, sql, function

The function below always returns ELSE value (which is 6) even if the SELECT query itself returns value 30.00 for example. In that case, the function should return number 4. Can anyone help me please?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION znamka(id_testu INT, id_studenta INT)
    RETURNS TINYINT
BEGIN
    DECLARE percenta FLOAT;
    SET percenta=
    (
        SELECT ROUND(tv.pocet_bodov/t.max_body*100, 2)
        FROM test t JOIN test_vysledky tv ON (tv.fk_test=t.id_test)
        WHERE tv.fk_test=id_testu AND tv.fk_student=id_studenta
    );
    RETURN CASE
        WHEN percenta>=90 THEN 1
        WHEN percenta<90 >=75 THEN 2
        WHEN percenta<75 >=50 THEN 3
        WHEN percenta<50 >=30 THEN 4
        WHEN percenta<30 THEN 5
        ELSE 6
    END;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: "WHEN percenta<90 >=75 THEN 2" etc is invalid syntax. Try "WHEN percenta between 75 and 89.9999 THEN 2" etc, or "WHEN percenta <90 and percenta >=75 THEN 2".

Comment: cast the float to int & then check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `CASE` statement to this:

```
RETURN CASE
    WHEN percenta >= 90 THEN 1
    WHEN (percenta < 90 AND percenta >=75) THEN 2
    WHEN (percenta < 75 AND percenta >=50) THEN 3
    WHEN (percenta < 50 AND percenta >=30) THEN 4
    WHEN percenta < 30 THEN 5
    ELSE 6
END;
```

Comments:

As @Drew mentioned in his comment, you will never hit your `ELSE` condition.  In addition, I'm surprised that MySQL was executing this function at all without any error.

Comment: Tim to the rescue. Too bad his ELSE makes no sense

Comment: still the same result (always 6). Drew, true, it doesnt make sense now, ill correct that later

Comment: Are you _certain_ your query is working as expected?  What happens if you hard code `percenta = 90` in your function?  Does the appropriate condition fire?

Comment: if I hardcode it to:
    SET percenta=90;
    RETURN percenta;
id does execute correctly

Comment: There is something going on in your query I believe, in addition to the problem you had with your `CASE` statement.

Comment: @Lopfest:  try to return `percenta` instead of the CASE to see the actual value

Comment: The weird thing is, when I leave the SET percenta=(SELECT statement);
and return the variable percenta, it doesn't return anything. Why is that so? (the hardcoded suggestion above did work)

Comment: My advice to you at this point is to take that query offline and figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: I figured out that there is actually problem with the INSERT statement, not the function.    
`INSERT INTO test_vysledky VALUES  
(10, 99, 9, znamka(10, 99));`  
this will insert always the ELSE value from function.    

But when i put it like below, with function stored in variable:  
SET @VAR=(SELECT znamka(10, 99));  
INSERT INTO test_vysledky VALUES  
(10, 99, 9, @VAR);  
then it chooses the correct CASE.    

Although this doesn't suit me, because there will be different function variables in each INSERT.  
Any ideas?

Comment: I am not too familiar with this problem, but I suspect that the source of the problem is that you are trying to `INSERT` a value into table `test_vysledky` which _itself_ comes from the very same table.  Can you change your logic?  I'll bet that if you run `znamka()` on another table you won't have this problem.

Comment: that was exactly the problem causing me trouble. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What's the datatype of those `pocet_bodov` and `max_body` columns? If it's INT you might get a truncated result. Try multiplication first:

```
SELECT ROUND(100*tv.pocet_bodov/t.max_body, 2)
```

Edit: Previous can't cause a problem in MySQL because it's not doing INTEGER calculation.

The SQL `CASE` statement is not the same as a C SWITCH; it stops at the *first* matching condition, there is no need to use `BETWEEN`:

```
RETURN CASE
    WHEN percenta >= 90 THEN 1
    WHEN percenta >=75) THEN 2
    WHEN percenta >=50) THEN 3
    WHEN percenta >=30) THEN 4
    WHEN percenta < 30 THEN 5
    ELSE 6 -- this will only be returned for NULLs
END;
```

Comment: those columns are both TINYINT UNSIGNED.